# how to post data from editable iframe

Tags: iframe, textarea

Hello I have an iframe on my website acting like a textarea.

```html
   <form action="my_parse_file.php" name="myform" id="myform" method="post">
<p><input name="title" placeholder="title" id="title" type="text" size="80"    maxlength="80"/></p>

<iframe id="textEditor" name="textEditor" style="width: 50%; height: 300px;"  scrolling="no">
</iframe>

  <input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I was wondering if it possible to post the data from it  to another page with php? I have tried posting it like I would a normal textarea:

```php
<?php
echo . $_POST['title'] .  . stripslashes($_POST['textEditor']);
?>
```

Maybe obviously, without success. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You'll have to capture the text from your editable iframe and append it to a hidden variable in your form.

Comment: thank you so much for answering, do you know/know of any website or way to do that?